# Type errors in function call expressions

Tags: python, types

I have dataclass and function with parameter type of that class.

```
from dataclass import dataclass 

@dataclass
class A:
  val_1: str = ""
  val_2: str = ""

def func(arg: A):
  print(arg.val_1, arg.val_2)
```

When I try to call method like this `func(arg=A)` I get warning "Expected type 'A', got 'Type[A]' instead". What is literally means?

Comment: It means that you declared that `arg` would be an instance of `A`, but you passed the class `A` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The type hint `arg: A` means that the argument should be an *instance of* `A`, because that's the typical use case. The *class* `A` itself is denoted as `Type[A]`, explicitly referring to the type itself (or any subclass thereof), which is a less common use case and hence has the more complex syntax.

When you call `func(A)`, you're passing `A`, the class itself, which does not match the type hint. You must pass an instance: `func(A())`.